# AWS redundant file share solution for Windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share

We are looking for a recommendation on setting up a redundant file share in AWS. AWS does provide the Amazon EFS (Elastic File Service), though it only supports NFS and doesn't play well with windows machines. It also seems Windows NFS support is pretty poor.

The EC2 VM's we'll be using, which need to access the file share, are Windows Server 2012R2 and AD joined. We would like to be able to have access to the files from at least 2 availability zones.

Amazon Storage Gateway was considered, though wanting access from two AZ's means there will be two writers pointing to one S3 bucket which is *not* recommended by Amazon.

Do we cluster two servers in two different AZ's? It seems like a lot of overhead and manual maintenance, but if that's the best approach...

Comment: I suggest you test EFS before you write it off. You could also consider [S3FS](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse), but I'd want extensive testing before I used it in production.

Comment: Are the Windows client VMs EC2 instances?  Or is this serving an on-prem Infrastructure?  Are the clients domain-joined?

Comment: Thank you @Tim. I did try EFS first and was unable to get windows to connect to NFS, and there is no good way to do it at a system level (e.g. symlink) it appears to only be available at a user level

Comment: @myron-semack EC2 in AWS VPC.

Comment: Are they Active Directory domain joined?

Comment: @myron-semack, yes AD Joined

Comment: @Tim From what I see, S3FS doesn't run on Windows. I do appreciate the suggestion!

Comment: There are other technologies that can make S3 look like a drive, open source and commercial, suggest you do a search as I can't recommend one over another. Also, you can probably get NFS4.1 clients for Windows that might let you use EFS. Caution is required though, when using things outside the way AWS support them.

Comment: Webdrive is a highly recommended drive on cloud solution